# Formula Workshop in Crystal Reports: Why does this not work in the formula workshop: {report_field1} or {report_field2}?

Tags: sql, if-statement, crystal-reports

In my report, {report_field1} shows up on a regular basis but when I change it to {report_field2}, it shows the values for it in the report but the places where {report_field1} should show it's values, it turns to 0.
So I am trying to make the report show that if {report_field1} values are 0 from the user, then it should show the {report_field2} values.

I tried to do it with an OR, AND statement but that does not work, is there any way to do what I am trying to do?

If there is no user input value for {report_field1} then it should print the user value {report_field2} and vice-versa

I am very new to Crystal Reports itself so I need some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create and use a formula like this:

```
IF {report_field1} = 0 THEN {report_field2} ELSE {report_field1}
```